# what is the difference between defining a vector as vector<int> v(n) vs vector<int> v[n]?

Tags: c++, vector

when I use this code:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<int>number[n];
  
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler marks 'n' as an error:
"expression must have a constant value" 
"the value of variable 'n' cannot be used as a constant"

but when I use `vector<int> v1(n)` instead, the error disappeared and worked well.

so, here is my questions:
what is the difference between defining a vector as `vector<int> v1(n)` vs `vector<int> v2[n]` ?
Do vectors use dynamic allocation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The difference is that one is a vector and one is an __array__ of  vectors.

Comment: Also, because `n` is dynamically read in at runtime, the code is invalid C++.  For a C-style array it needs to be a constant (`const` or `constexpr`).

Comment: Terminology note: Anything that can change size or shape is dynamic. That said, nothing in C++ ever really changes size. `vector` is always the same size. The array it points to never changes size. What happens is when vector needs a different sized array, it makes a new array, copies the old array into it, frees the old array and points at the new array. Nothing changed size, it just got replaced.

Answer (score 1):

```
type_name variable_name[array_size];
```

Is syntax for a default initialised array variable. `vector<int>number[n];` is an array of n vectors. If the size is not compile time constant - such as it isn't in the example, then the program is ill-formed as evidenced by the error that you quoted.

```
type_name variable_name(args);
```

Is syntax for direct initialisation of a variable.

> Do vectors use dynamic allocation?

As with most standard containers (all except `std::array`), vector elements are dynamic objects. It acquires the storage using the allocator that has been provided to it.

Answer (score 1):

##### Difference between the two definitions

- `vector<int> v1(n)` defines a single vector that contains `n` elements.
- `vector<int> v2[n]` defines a variable sized array of vectors, each of which will contain no elements.
  This is commonly called a `VLA` (Variable Length Array) and [not officially part of C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) (it **is** part of C99 however). Some compilers like gcc do support it for c++ as well, but you shouldn't count on it.

##### `std::vector` allocation

`std::vectors` will allocate their elements with the provided allocator (the second template argument `std::vector<T,Allocator>`).

By default this will be `std::allocator<T>`, which will use `new` & `delete` - i.e. it'll be allocated on the free store (mostly implemented as a heap).

You can provide a different allocator though if you want to use some other allocation strategy ([heres](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator) what you would need to implement for a custom allocator)